# Cannot read from /tmp with PostgreSQL COPY, but able to read the same file from another directory with the exact same permissions

Tags: postgresql, linux, postgresql-9.4

I have a file `/tmp/foo.csv` that looks like this:

```
1,2
10,20
100,200
```

I have the same exact file in another directory `/mydata/foo.csv`. Both directories *and* files have *the same exact permissions, owner, and were created by the same user*, yet when I run

```
COPY foo FROM '/tmp/foo.csv' (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ',', HEADER TRUE);
```

I get this error

```
ERROR:  could not open file "/tmp/foo.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
```

When I run

```
COPY foo FROM '/mydata/foo.csv' (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ',', HEADER TRUE);
```

I see `COPY 3`.

What am I missing here?

Here's the relevant file and directory information:

```
╭─foo@bar  / ‹py27› 
╰─$ ll -d /mydata /mydata/foo.csv /tmp /tmp/foo.csv                                                                                                                       1 ↵
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root 4.0K Sep  9 08:26  /mydata
drwxrwxrwt 17 root root  420 Sep  9 08:57  /tmp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   17 Sep  6 12:03  /mydata/foo.csv
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   17 Sep  9 08:36  /tmp/foo.csv
╭─foo@bar  / ‹py27› 
╰─$ diff /mydata/foo.csv /tmp/foo.csv
╭─foo@bar  / ‹py27› 
╰─$
```

I'm running Arch Linux

**NOTE:** I've also tried this on another Linux machine running CentOS and I was unable to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `COPY` reads from the server where the database you connect to is.  Can it be that you have `foo.csv` on the server only in one location, but you show here the listings of your local machine?

Comment: I'm running the server on my local machine.

Comment: And you can do a `cat` from both files as user `postgres`?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to do that.

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled in your Arch install?

Comment: I do not have SELinux installed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Arch, the systemd script for PostgreSQL (`/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service`) enables [private /tmp](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ServicesPrivateTmp), which means the PostgreSQL server process can't communicate with the user using /tmp.

Two possible solutions:

1. Create a new folder somewhere else and give user `postgres` read privileges on it: `# sudo mount -t tmpfs -o users,rw tmpfs /data`
2. (NOT RECOMMENDED) Set `PrivateTmp` option in postgresql.service to `false`.